# Complex Dice Roller App in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am in the process of building a complex dice roller in Android Studio. Which takes the users input and preforms the calculations. I have figured out how to get it to either add or subtract the string using the .split function. However I cannot get it to both add AND subtract depending on which operator is in the equation. Attached is a picture of the code that only adds. [Complex Roller Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWGr9.png) Below is the code that doesnt work, where I am trying to get it to both add and subtract. if any can help me out i would appreciate it.

public void rolls(){

```
String equationAdd = et_roll1.getText().toString();
String equationSubtract = et_roll1.getText().toString();
String[]rollsAdd = equationAdd.split("\\+");
String[]rollsSubtract = equationSubtract.split("-");

for (String dieTypeAdd:rollsAdd)
{
    for (String dieTypeSubtract:rollsSubtract){
    String[] dieDataAdd = dieTypeAdd.split("d");
    String[] dieDataSubtract = dieTypeSubtract.split("d");
    if (dieDataAdd.length > 1)
    {
        int dieQty = Integer.parseInt(dieDataAdd[0]);
        int dieFace = Integer.parseInt(dieDataAdd[1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < dieQty; i++)
        {
            int roll = r.nextInt(dieFace);
            sumAdd += roll;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int modifier = Integer.parseInt(dieDataAdd[0]);
        sumAdd += modifier;
    }
    if (dieDataSubtract.length > 1)
    {
        int dieQty = Integer.parseInt(dieDataSubtract[0]);
        int dieFace = Integer.parseInt(dieDataSubtract[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < dieQty; i++)
        {
            int roll = r.nextInt(dieFace);
            sumSubtract -= roll;
        }
    }
    else
    {
       int modifier = Integer.parseInt(dieDataSubtract[0]);
        sumSubtract -= modifier;
    }
}}
```

}

Comment: it should also be noted that I am building this is a "testbed" project in order to make sure it is in proper working before implementing into my actual project. So the naming convention isnt locked in stone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer for anyone that might be looking in the future:

```
static void rolls(){
    //tells the progrom what characters to split the string by, "A" allows for either "+" or "-" at the begininning of the string
    Pattern expressionFormat = Pattern.compile("((\\A|\\+|\\-){1}(\\d+[d])?\\d+)");

    String equationAdd = et_roll1.getText().toString();

    Matcher matcher = expressionFormat.matcher(equationAdd);

    String rollsAdd = "";

    while(matcher.find()){ 
        rollsAdd = matcher.group();
        String[] diedataArray = rollsAdd.split("(\\+|\\-)"); //tells the program to isolate values with either "+" or "-"
        String dieData = diedataArray[0];
        if (diedataArray[0].length() == 0) {
            dieData = diedataArray[1];
        }
        //splits the users input data further by looking for a value of "d", the number to the left of the "d" = times to roll, the number to the right of the "d" = number of faces on the die
        if (rollsAdd.length() > 2){
            dieDataAdd = dieData.split("d");
            int dieQty = Integer.parseInt(dieDataAdd[0]);
            int dieFace = Integer.parseInt(dieDataAdd[1]);
            int rollSum = 0;

            //rolls a dice based on the users input....ie. 1d6 rolls a single 6 sides dice, 3d20 rolls 3 different 20 sides dice
            for (int i = 0; i < dieQty; i++){
                roll = r.nextInt(dieFace)+1;
                rollSum += roll;
            }
            //program speicially looks for the "-" operator and then adds the value to the sumSubtract variable
            if (rollsAdd.charAt(0) == '-'){
                sumSubtract += rollSum;
            }
            // if the operator is "+", add its value to sumAdd variable
            else{
                sumAdd += rollSum;
            }
        }
        //this accounts for any whole numbers that are not dice.....ie. 1d6+2, 2 being the modifier of the roll
        else{
            int modifier = Integer.parseInt(rollsAdd);
            modTotal += modifier;
        }
        //these 2 IF statements test to see which value is the highest, then subtracts (only works if user inputs subtraction) the highest first in order to "always" show a positive number
        if (sumAdd > sumSubtract){
            sum = sumAdd - sumSubtract + modTotal;
        }
        else if (sumSubtract > sumAdd){
            sum = sumSubtract - sumAdd + modTotal;
        }
        else{
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```